# How can I set array as a key value in javascript object?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I am trying to set an array as a key value in a JSON object using javascript.

When I set the array value,

console.log(obj["likes"]) displays an array of size 1.

but on  the next line 
console.log(obj) shows that the likes key is an array of size 0.

I have a JSON object that has information about posts.

If no likes exist on a post then that field does not exist in that post's objects.

I am trying to implement a like-dislike update function, where I check if a user has liked a post.

If he hasn't then I append his username to the array of likes else I remove his username.

userID is a global variable that I define at the start of the script tag.

It works if instead of userID, I set a new string like:

```
obj["likes"] = ["XX"]
```

This works too (i get an extra space but it atleast logs correctly):

```
obj["likes"] = [userId+" "]
console.log(obj["likes"])
console.log("Obj:",obj)
```

But then doing this again does not work!!!!

```
let arr = [" "+userId]
console.log(arr)
arr[0] = arr[0].trim()
console.log(arr)
obj["likes"] = arr
console.log("Obj:",obj)
```

```
function saveLikeDislike(url, action) {
        for (i = 0; i < crawledUrlsData.length; i += 1) {

            if (typeof crawledUrlsData[i] === "object") {

                var obj = crawledUrlsData[i]

                if (url === obj["url"]) {

                    if (action === "like") {

                        if ("likes" in obj) {
                            likes = obj["likes"]
                            if (likes.includes(userId)) {
                                likes = likes.filter(id => id != userId)
                            } else {
                                likes.push(userId)
                            }
                            obj["likes"] = likes
                        } else {
                            var id = window.userId
                            console.log(userId)

                            obj["likes"] = [id]
                            console.log(obj["likes"])
                            console.log("Obj:",obj)
                        }

                        if ("dislikes" in obj) {
                            var dislikes = obj["dislikes"]

                            if (dislikes.includes(userId)) {
                                dislikes = dislikes.filter(id => id != userId)
                                obj["dislikes"] = dislikes
                            }
                        }

                    } else {

                        if ("dislikes" in obj) {
                            dislikes = obj["dislikes"]
                            if (dislikes.includes(userId)) {
                                dislikes = dislikes.filter(id => id != userId)
                            } else {
                                dislikes.push(userId)
                            }
                            obj["dislikes"] = dislikes
                        } else 
                            obj["dislikes"] = [dislikes]
                        }

                        if ("likes" in obj) {
                            var likes = obj["likes"]

                            if (likes.includes(userId)) {
                                likes = likes.filter(id => id != userId)
                                obj["likes"] = likes
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    crawledUrlsData[i] = obj
                    console.log(obj["likes"])

                    renderData()
                    return
                }
        }
    }
```

[image: console output]

Comment: yes yes. Was a typo. See my recent edit...

Comment: I only looked at where you said "But then doing this again does not work!!!!"..  I copied and pasted that code and it works as expected... the final obj is an array of array, like this: obj["likes"][0]. So you can check that obj["likes"][0] === arr[0]  and it will be true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turnes out I had missed a parenthesis.

But this still does not explain the odd behavior where on one line key value was set and the very next line the output from console.log was different when accessing userId but proper if userId was modified in some way.

Anyway, here's the fixed function:

```
function saveLikeDislike(url, action) {
    for (i = 0; i < crawledUrlsData.length; i += 1) {

        if (typeof crawledUrlsData[i] === "object" && crawledUrlsData[i]["url"] == url) {

            var obj = crawledUrlsData[i]

            if (url === obj["url"]) {

                if (action === "like") {

                    if ("likes" in obj) {
                        console.log("likes in obj")
                        likes = obj["likes"]
                        if (likes.includes(userId)) {
                            likes = likes.filter(id => id != userId)
                        } else {
                            likes.push(userId)
                        }
                        obj["likes"] = likes
                    } else {

                        obj.likes = [userId]
                        console.log("Obj:",obj)
                    }

                    if ("dislikes" in obj) {
                        var dislikes = obj["dislikes"]
                        console.log("Dislikes: ",dislikes)
                        if (dislikes.includes(userId)) {
                            dislikes = dislikes.filter(id => id != userId)
                            obj["dislikes"] = dislikes
                        }
                    }

                } else if (action === "dislike"){

                    if ("dislikes" in obj) {
                        dislikes = obj["dislikes"]
                        if (dislikes.includes(userId)) {
                            dislikes = dislikes.filter(id => id != userId)
                        } else {
                            dislikes.push(userId)
                        }
                        obj["dislikes"] = dislikes
                    } else {
                        obj["dislikes"] = [userId]
                    }
                    if ("likes" in obj) {
                        var likes = obj["likes"]
                        console.log("ID: ",userId)
                        if (likes.includes(userId)) {
                            likes = likes.filter(id => id != userId)
                            obj["likes"] = likes
                        }
                    }
                }    
            }

                crawledUrlsData[i] = obj

                linkTreeRef.set(crawledUrlsData)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems.
1. That usrId - userId typo randomSoul has mentioned.
2. This line:

```
likes = likes.push(userId)
```

The output of `likes.push(something)` is a number, the length of the array after push. This line will amount to `likes = 1`. Do instead:

```
likes.push(userId)
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. This would be the next error I would have to debug. But this is not the source of problem rn. The lines below it are where the problem lies. I think this is happening because userID is a global variable. Can you tell me how to access it correctly? See my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

`push` returns the new length of the array - so this line:

```
likes = likes.push(userId);
```

Will be a number, not an array - remove the assignment:

```
likes.push(userId);
```

Comment: hey, thanks for pointing that out. But the issue is in the else part below it. I think this is happening as userID is defined in global scope.

Comment: I mean userId not userID